# Google Geochart: Load on trigger

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Geochart.js in my project and i would like to know an way to specify when the map is drawn, and i can't just do it on page load because the user needs to enter some data first.

Is there an way to just trigger an function and only then it loads or refreshes the map?

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, include some code.

Comment: @iohans I have googled a lot but most solutions where to use listeners but that's not what i need

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the listener for 'ready'?

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
   // Your function here
});
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addlistener